# Limiting distribution of $Y_n=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^3}$ where $X_i$'s are i.i.d $N(0,1)$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, weak-convergence, probability-limit-theorems

Suppose $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ are i.i.d standard normal variables. I am looking for the limiting distribution of $$Y_n=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^3}$$

Since $E(X_1^3)=0$, I don't think I can use the law of large numbers or Slutsky's theorem.

I can rewrite $Y_n$ as $$Y_n=\frac{\sqrt n\cdot\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}{\sqrt n\cdot\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^3}$$

In this form, the numerator has a $N(0,1)$ distribution and the denominator is asymptotically $N(0,15)$ by CLT. But does this help me in any way?

Characteristic function of $Y_n$ is of the form

$$E\left[e^{itY_n}\right]=\frac1{(\sqrt{2\pi})^n}\int_{\mathbb R^n} \exp\left\{it\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^3}-\frac12\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\right\}\,dx_1\ldots dx_n$$

I am not sure if this readily simplifies either. Any suggestion would be great.

---

Based on the answer by @Chris Janjigian, it can be said that

$$Y_n \stackrel{d}\longrightarrow a+bY$$

for some $a,b \in \mathbb R$, where $Y$ has a standard Cauchy distribution.

Comment: Does the Delta Method not work here?

Comment: Amusing downvote. If someone thinks this is trivial or just another application of Delta method, I would be genuinely interested in their answer below.

Comment: Yeah I think the usual Delta Method does not work here because the function f(x, y) = x/y is not differentiable at x = y = 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call the numerator $A_n$ and the denominator $B_n$. By the multidimensional CLT $(A_n/\sqrt{n}, B_n/\sqrt{n})$ converges jointly in distribution to a mean zero 2D Normal random variable $(A,B)$ with Var$(A) = 1$, Var(B) = 15 and Cov(A,B) = $3$ (consider the 2D vectors $(X_i,X_i^3)$ as your sample). You can then apply the continuous mapping theorem to see that $A_n/B_n$ converges to $A/B$. The distribution of this random variable can be computed by hand using change-of-variables and it is [generalized Cauchy distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution#Correlated_central_normal_ratio).

Comment: I was thinking of other ways of doing this but looks like this is the only way. What do you take the continuous function to be? $g(x,y)=\frac{x}{y}$ for $y\ne 0$?

Comment: @StubbornAtom yes. For continuous mapping, you just need that the discontinuity set of the function (which is $\{(x,y) : y = 0\}$ for that function) has probability zero under the limit distribution.

Comment: Okay. Would you say that the multivariate delta method is not applicable here?

Comment: @StubbornAtom Perhaps there is a delta method more general than the one I know, but the thing I know called the delta method is essentially just Taylor's theorem applied to the CLT limit and results in a normal limiting distribution (or positive powers of a normal). Since the limit here is not normal or a power of a normal, I don't see how one would use it. That said, that does not mean that no such argument exists. I often miss things.